# My VideoObject isn't being picked up in my Django blog app. Does Google need time to update?

Tags: django, video, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I added the appropriate markup but my videos are not showing up in Google search video tab.

Here is my markup:

```
        {% block content %}
    <div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
        <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="{{post.image_url}}" />
        <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="{{post.video_path}}" />
        <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="{{ post.publish }}" />
        <h2 id="detail-h1">
            <span itemprop="name">{{ post.title }}</span>
        </h2>

        {% if post.video %}
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe  src="{{post.video_path}}?autoplay=1&autohide=1" class="embed-responsive-item"
            frameborder="0" controls="0" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
            </div>
        {% else %}


            {% if post.image_url %}
                <img src="{{post.image_url}}"  class="img-responsive">
            {% else %}
                <p>upload an image</p>
            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}


        <div style="margin-top: 10px; background: white; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
            <span>
            <p style="float: left">
                {% if post.author %}
                    Author: {{post.author}}
                {% endif %}
            </p>
            <p style="float: right" id="pub">
                {%if post.draft %}<span id="draft">Draft </span>{% endif %} Publicado: {{ post.publish|date }}
            </p>
            </span>

        <p class="tags" style="clear: both">Tags:

        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}">
                {{ tag.name }}
            </a>
                {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        </p>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <p>
                <a href="{% url 'blog:delete' post.id %}" class="btn" role="button">delete</a>
                <a href="{% url 'blog:update' post.slug %}"  class="btn" role="button">edit</a>
            </p>
        {% endif %}

        <p>Share on:
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"
            class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" target="_blank">
            <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
            </a>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status={{ instance.content | truncatechars:80 | urlify }}%20{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"
            class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" target="_blank">
            <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
            </a>



            <a href='https://plus.google.com/share?url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}'
            class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google" target="_blank">
            <span class="fa fa-google"></span>
            </a>


            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}&title={{
            instance.title }}&summary={{ share_string }}&source={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"
            class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" target="_blank">
            <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
            </a>
        </p>




    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; background: white; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <p class="content-markdown"><span itemprop="description">{{post.body}}</span></p>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; background: white; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
        <div id="disqus_thread"></div>


    </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}



    {% block aside %}

        <h3 class="">Similar Posts</h3>
        <hr style="margin:10px">

    <div class="row">
        {% for post in similar_posts %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12" id="similar">
            <div class="thumbnail thumb">
                <h6 id="date">{{ post.publish|date }}</h6>

                {% if post.image %}
                    <img src="{{post.image.url}}"  class="img-responsive post">
                {% elif post.image_url %}
                    <img src="{{post.image_url}}"  class="img-responsive post">
                {% else %}
                    <p>upload an image</p>
                {% endif %}

                <div class="caption">
                    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                        <h5 class="post-title" id="title">{{post.title}}</h5>
                    </a>

                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <p>
                            <a href="{% url 'blog:delete' post.id %}" class="btn" role="button">delete</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'blog:update' post.slug %}"  class="btn" role="button">edit</a>
                        </p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% empty %}
            <p id="para">There are no similar posts yet.</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endblock aside %}
```

Today is Sunday May 8th 2016. I did this about 11:30 last night.

Does Google need to update its systems for it to show up? I ran it throught the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) and It worked. I got a green check on my VideoObject. So Google is sensing it but it's not showing.

Another thing: My blog doesn't host videos. The videos are embeds from YouTube. When someone clicks the link on Google, will it send them to my site or to the source of the embed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sounds more like an SEO question.

Comment: I agree that this question is not on-topic here. It might be on [webmasters.se], but there it will likely be a duplicate (tl;dr: it can take a long time, and it might even never show up, even if everything is correct). In general, for future questions: If you ask about the markup (instead of something specific to Django), you should not include the Django code, but the end result (i.e., the generated HTML).

Comment: Doesn't SEO involve code though